# Какие ещё глаголы имеют "странное" прошедшее время (как "шли")?

Tags: этимология, словообразование

Прошедшее время "шли" совсем не похоже на начальную форму "идти". Какие ещё есть такие глаголы? Почему так получилось?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это явление (образование форм одного слова от разных корневых основ) называется супплетивизмом. В русском языке супплетивизм у прошедшего времени глагола проявляется в единственном случае: "идти" - "шел". Все остальные примеры (включая "быть") супплетивными в прошедшем времени не являются, они просто "неправильные" т.е. образованы нестандартными способами от той же корневой основы.
Глагол "быть" является супплетивным в настоящем времени  (быть - [он] есть), ранее имел аналогичные формы для всех лиц.

Также супплетивными считаются формы человек-люди и год-лет, а также повелительное наклонение от глагола "ехать" - "поезжай" (хотя на очень древнем уровне последние глаголы родственны) и некоторые другие (примеры есть в других ответах).

Не являются супплетивными глаголы класть-(по)ложить, поскольку чередование корней происходит не на уровне формобразования, а при словообразовании.

Answer (score 3):

Данные слова имеют супплетивные формы, т.е.формы одного и того же слова, образованные от разных корней или основ.Например: брать-взять, говорить-сказать, ловить- поймать; 
прилагательные:плохой-хуже, много-больше, хороший-лучше;
существительные: человек-люди
местоимения: я- меня

Answer (score 1):

Потому что эти глаголы очень древние и обозначают какие-либо базовые понятия. Можно сравнить с русским глаголом "быть", у которого тоже при спряжении меняется основа ("быть" - "был" - "будет", но в наст. вр. - "есть"). Точно такое же явление имеет место и в других языках. Например, в английском спряжение глагола to be (am, is, was/were и пр.).

В русском языке эти глаголы относятся к изолированным, т.е. глаголы при образовании личных форм наст. вр. имеющие свои особые системы окончаний и свои особые соотношения основ. Само явление образования таких форм называется [супплетивизмом](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC)

Comment: То есть только "идти" и "быть"?

Comment: Ну, если есть (ел – едят), дать (дал – дадут) и пр. не вызывают вопроса, что они совсем не похожи на начальную форму, то, наверное, да

Comment: Быть - был - будет - это формы, образованные от одного корня, подвергшегося сильным фонетическим изменениям. От другой основы образованы формы личные настоящего времени: [Аз] есьм .. [Он] есть .. [они] суть.